# Why does Python take so much time to exit? How do I reduce that time?

Tags: python

My code looks like something like this:

```
print "Loading"
data = load_data()
do_work(data)
print "Done
```

Load data loads a huge JSON file (about 2GB, 8GB once loaded in memory) using `ujson`.
The problem is that once I see "Done" printed, Python does NOT exit until after a minute. This is exacerbated with bigger files.

I'm on Python 2.7.8 [GCC 4.9.3] on Linux.

Comment: probably memory swapping. not sure that json is the best way when the data is that big.

Comment: is part of `do_work()` writing back large amounts to file? perhaps file write buffers are waiting to be flushed..

Comment: @Aaron, no, no writing in `do_work()`.

Comment: In case anyone is interested on updates on this, we are currently loading 200GB into memory, we use ujson and it takes up to 10 min for Python to cleanup. I've been killing the process and have not seen any ill-effects. Still, I'd like a better way to handle this.

Answer (score 1):

once the program is completed, Python needs to release the memory used by the program. If you use a lot of memory, and/or memory structures are complex, it might take a few seconds (maybe up to a minute). This is a part of Python architecture and you can't really do anything about that given you have to keep these data structures in memory.

Comment: I've been killing the process. Should I not do that? What happens with that memory, is the OS not going to reclaim it? Is there a way to force Python to just leave its garbage up and let the OS handle it?

Comment: usually one minute is an absolute maximum even for much bigger amounts of data, so I might be wrong and you discovered a bug. OS is capable to clean up after a process, but is is not guaranteed to release all memory/resources and used only in "emergency" cases, such as killing the process. So, Python attempts to clean up anyway

Comment: I would second Aaron, if you don't have to store the data in memory entirely and stream instead, it would likely solve the problem. Just in case you found a bug, can you share the JSON file to check if it is a memory management issue?

Comment: @Marat yah, then I realized that the stdlib python `json` library can only stream *encode* not decode.. there are some iterative json parser implementations floating around, but I try to stick with stdlib here on S.O.

Comment: I cannot stream the data since it's a lookup table that I need to have fully available. Inside of `do_work()` I do stream other data, also in JSON (smaller objects in separate lines) and but that doesn't seem to affect the "unloading" time.

Comment: I cannot share the data; the only particularity that I noticed is that the keys are relatively long strings and because `ujson` doesn't do string interning (http://guilload.com/python-string-interning/), that is bloating up the used memory. Still, vanilla json exhibited similar problems and was much slower in other parts of the code.

Comment: @JosepValls instead of worrying about interning, could you just trash the full key and only keep a hash?

Comment: I should had mentioned that besides the keys being long, for each entry, there are a lot of long keys as well. I did a script that would replace the keys for smaller ones but the dictionaries were still very large (because of how Pyhon handles dictionary resizing; and no, I cannot use named tuples or classes with __slots__ because the objects are not homogeneous).
I was hoping for something I can pass to the interpreter or tweak the GC.